# How to use Google Maps on iOS using Xamarin.Forms.Maps?

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm trying to use Google Maps on iOS in my Xamarin.Forms app using the Xamarin.Forms.Maps nuget package instead of iOS Maps.

I've tried using the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps and Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.V2 but to no avail, it kept breaking things I don't know if it doesn't work with the current versions of Xamarin.Forms 5.0 or something but I even tried with brand new projects and it kept breaking the compilation with the gcc compiler after doing the setup following various tutorials such as https://nerd-corner.com/how-to-integrate-google-maps-in-an-app-with-xamarin/ or the Xamarin.Forms Google Maps course on Pluralsight but nothing worked.

So I started using Xamarin.Forms.Maps and everything works but I'm trying to use Google Maps on iOS instead of Maps.

I've looked all over the internet for it but it seems there's only hacks available ( such as the app will use Google Maps if it is installed on the device otherwise it will use Maps ) and I can't risk using hacks.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The standard Forms Maps uses the built in Maps implementation for the Platform - on iOS this means Apple Maps.  You can use Google maps on iOS by using the Google Maps plugin.  If you are having problems with this plugin, you should post a question about those specific errors so we can help you.  Since the only details you've given us is "it kept breaking things" and "nothing worked" there is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @Jason I will try, however do you know if I should use Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps or Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.V2 with Xamarin.Forms 5.0 ?

Comment: I have no idea why there are two different repos

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else can help ? Is there any hacks we can do to get Google Maps on iOS without using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps as this package seems to not work with the new versions on Xamarin ?